# google map markers php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps-markers

I am able to display my mp ok, but when I go to add markers it is no longer loading the map... i.e. when I add the latter php code to my initialize function it doesn't work! Any ideas??!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var map = null;

    function addMarker(lat, lng){

        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: point,
            map: map
        });

    }
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: {lat: 54.872128, lng: -6.284874},
            zoom: 15
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                mapOptions);

        <?php        
        $query = mysqli_query("select * from tester") or die(mysqli_error());
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ 
                $lat = $row['lat'];
                $lng = $row['lng'];
                echo ("addMarker($lat, $lng);");
                ?>

  }


    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


</script>

<div id="map-canvas" style="height:600px; width:600px;
     margin-top:100px; margin-bottom: 100px;
     ">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with the scope of `map`, in your initialize function you are redeclaring it inside that scope instead of populating the previous map var, remove the `var` from your function as follows:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions); //Note i've removed the "var" keyword from this line.
```

**A little more explanation:**

`var map = null;` -> declared in global scope.

`var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);` -> declared inside `initialize` function scope.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: point,
    map: map // -> NULL because it will look for map in the parent scope.
});
```

I've found the issue, you are missing the closing bracers of your while statement:

```
<?php        
    $query = mysqli_query("select * from tester") or die(mysqli_error());
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $lat = $row['lat'];
        $lng = $row['lng'];
        echo ("addMarker($lat, $lng);");
    } //Missing!!!
?>
```

Comment: When i remove the php from my initialize() function the map loads ok, but with the php in nothing loads at all...

Comment: Does the file where you print the javascript code have a .php extension? if not, the php will never be evaluated.

Comment: Also, do you get any error in your developers console?

Comment: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' in relation to <?php... and yes, it's a php file!

Comment: Can you paste the function after the php has processed it? Copy it from the source code once the page has done loading.

Comment: Check my last edit, you are missing the closing bracers of the while loop